# Voltage measurement at different adc ground

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis

I'm trying to measure a voltage drop across a resistor divider with a supply from ldo. The single ended adc is connected as follows. Will the adc readings give the expected readings if the gnd1 and gnd2 are not connected?

[image: edited]

---

Update added November 27:

Thanks a lot from your inputs.

So I've managed to make this work by having GND1 = GND2.

Comment: If there is no other connection, no!

Comment: *WHY* are the two grounds not connected?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake with the sketch. There should be a diff amp across the r1 then the single ended output of it goes to adc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not work. The microcontroller ADC will measure the input voltage relative to its local ground. If this is not connected to the other ground, then this measurement will not accurately reflect the difference between the LDO output and Gnd 1. It's even possible that the `to ADC` signal is outside the power supply rails of the microcontroller, and could damage the micro.

If the ADC has a differential input option, and you can arrange that the 'To ADC' signal and 'Gnd 1' voltage will always be within the recommended input voltage range of the ADC, then you could measure this voltage using two connections and the differential mode of the ADC.

Otherwise, your options include

- Use an external ADC grounded to 'Gnd 1' (and possibly some isolated data transfer mechanism like opto-couplers).
- Use a "high-linearity optocoupler" (for example, HCNR-201) with an appropriate feedback circuit to transfer the analog voltage between the two ground domains.

Comment: I see. If I place a diff amp across R1 then say have a gain that is within the ADC range, will this work? (the MCU ADC is connected to an embedded linux board which powered by usb through the mains. Moreover, the ldo is fed by 12v input dc adapter also connected to the mains ). With these connections, will gnd1 and gnd2 be equal?

Comment: @ssof, that's not enough information to answer. Edit your question to include a complete schematic and it might be possible to answer,.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the image above

Answer (score 2):

> Will the ADC readings give the expected readings if the gnd1 and gnd2 are not connected?

Only if you expect wildly varying readings.

The problem is that you don't have a "circuit". You are expecting a small current to flow into the ADC input but you have provided no return path. The "circuit" is open so no current can flow. As drawn your ADC input just has a large antenna connected to it so it will be prone to picking up electro-magnetic noise and this will cause random readings from the ADC.

Edit your question to explain what the real problem is and what you have tried to get around it. Someone will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DPDT relay to sample the voltage on the left, then flip the relay to place the (1uF? 0.1uF? 0.01uF) capacitor across the ADC input/gnd.

ADCs, if a successive approximation ADC with moderate # of bits, usually have about 10pF of Cin (that provides, with sqrt(K*T/C) a 20 microvolt RMS floor).
If your relay charges 1,000X that 10pF, or 0.01uF cap, and then places that 0.01uF across the ADC input, you'll have a slight gain error but a fine and isolated voltage acquisition system.

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you would like to find the voltage across the resistor divider, you may have to connect the node above R2 to the ADC input of the uC. Two different grounds can be at different voltages given that you've not connected them. To know the maximum error in your measurement, you can check the LDO and your micro-controller's data sheet to find the worst case ground bounce and/or ground dc value shift. Now the LDO's ground will shift based on many parameters like the current drawn or sinked, amount of de-caps present to ripple out ground noise injected by power switching circuits etc. Depending on the LDO you buy, you may have a way to ensure the ground voltage by connecting the thermal power pad to a ground plane (if you plan on using it in a Pcb).